# Relationship between generalized momentum and momentum operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

For each spacetime point $x$, we can define generalized momentum $\pi(x)$, where generalized coordinate is $\phi(x)$ (or quantum field). How is this generalized momentum related to actual momentum operator, where integration is done over entire spacetime?

I know that we get momentum operator out of stress-energy tensor, and we get stress-energy tensor from translation conservation using Lagrangian. But then it is really hard to spot connection between generalized momentum and momentum operator, thus the question.

What would happen also for general curved spacetime for relation? I expect things not to be that much different.

Comment: No relation. The naming is due to historical reasons.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Not even explicit mathematical relation? I know these two are different concepts, but there is no relation other than stress-energy tensor thing?

Comment: Mathematical relation: $P_i\sim\int \pi\partial_i\phi$, so you can write the momentum operator as a function of the canonical momentum. But that's also true for all Noether charges (the Hamiltonian, the angular momentum, the electric charge...).